# MyFaces app doesn't work on Weblogic 12c

Tags: java, spring, weblogic, myfaces

I've got an application which is working perfectly fine on Weblogic 11. But when trying to run it on weblogic 12c, I get this exception:

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Factories configured for this Application. This happens if the faces-initialization does not work at all - make sure that you properly include all configuration settings necessary for a basic faces application and that all the necessary libs are included. Also check the logging output of your web application and your container for any exceptions!
If you did that and find nothing, the mistake might be due to the fact that you use some special web-containers which do not support registering context-listeners via TLD files and a context listener is not setup in your web.xml.
A typical config looks like this;
<listener>
  <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder._getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:286)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:206)
    ...
```

I've got this listener in my web.xml. I've gone through the first two pages on google search on this topic, but didn't find any solution.

I use:

- Apache MyFaces 2.1.10
- Servlet API 2.5
- Spring 3.2.4

Requested: web.xml

```
    <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
             version="2.4">

        <!--
          - ####################
          - Spring configuration
          - ####################
        //-->

        <session-config>
            <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
        </session-config>

        <!--
          - Declaration of the SPRING MVC dispatcher servlet.
        //-->
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <!--load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup-->
        </servlet>

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>pibEmailServlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.teamead.fwf.web.PibEmailServlet</servlet-class>
        </servlet>

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>overviewForward</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.teamead.fwf.web.OverviewForwardServlet</servlet-class>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>overviewForward</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/showMenu/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>pibEmailServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/sendPibEmail</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>aipUpdateServlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.teamead.fwf.web.AipUpdateServlet</servlet-class>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>aipUpdateServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/aip/update</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>aipUpdateServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/aip/reset</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

         <servlet>
            <servlet-name>validationServlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.teamead.fwf.web.servlet.ValidationServlet</servlet-class>

        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>validationServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/validationServlet</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/pib.html</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/pib.pdf</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/pib.xml</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <!--
          - Specifies the context location for the root application context of this web app.
          - The value mentioned here is the default of the ContextLoaderListener.
        //-->
        <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/spring/properties-config.xml
                /WEB-INF/spring/menu/menu-config.xml
                /WEB-INF/spring/captcha-service.xml
                /WEB-INF/spring/custom-message-service.xml
                /WEB-INF/spring/data-access.xml
                /WEB-INF/spring/data-source.xml
                /WEB-INF/spring/service-definition.xml
                /WEB-INF/spring/domain-service.xml
                /WEB-INF/spring/spring-security-config.xml
                /WEB-INF/spring/cms-config.xml
                /WEB-INF/spring/predefined-pib.xml
                /WEB-INF/spring/fwf-services-manager.xml
            </param-value>
        </context-param>

        <!-- Theme settings for FLAVOUR -->
        <!--context-param>
            <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
            <param-value>#{siteService.siteTag}-THEME</param-value>
        </context-param-->

        <!--If this is not set, the XML comments in pages are rendered as components(i.e. in panelGrid)-->
        <context-param>
            <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <!--<listener>
             <listener-class>com.bea.p13n.http.SessionMonitor</listener-class>
        </listener>-->
        <!--
          - Listener, to allow Jetty serving MyFaces apps.
        //-->
        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
        </listener>

        <!--
          - Loads the specified root application context of this web app at startup,
          - by default from "/WEB-INF/services.xml".
        //-->
        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>

        <!--
          - ##################################
          - Tomahawk MyFaces JSF configuration
          - ##################################
        //-->
        <context-param>
            <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.JSF_JS_MODE</param-name>
            <param-value>minimal-modern</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <context-param>
            <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
            <param-value>Production</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <context-param>
            <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
            <param-value>server</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <context-param>
            <param-name>javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <context-param>
            <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.COMPRESS_STATE_IN_SESSION</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <context-param>
            <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.SERIALIZE_STATE_IN_SESSION</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
         </context-param>

        <context-param>
            <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.NUMBER_OF_VIEWS_IN_SESSION</param-name>
            <param-value>30</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <context-param>
            <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
            <param-value>.jspx</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <context-param>
            <param-name>facelets.VIEW_MAPPINGS</param-name>
            <param-value>/public/*;/restricted/*;/ajaxlogin/*;/mobile/*</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <context-param>
            <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.CHECK_ID_PRODUCTION_MODE</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </context-param>
        <!-- ONLY FOR WEBLOGIC DEPLOYMENT -->
        <context-param>
            <param-name>facelets.REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
            <param-value>2</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <context-param>
            <param-name>primefaces.PRIVATE_CAPTCHA_KEY</param-name>
            <param-value>6Ldx8eYSAAAAAI7A7Ln5GjOvQ88YD5HwwXV-KyUR</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <context-param>
            <param-name>primefaces.PUBLIC_CAPTCHA_KEY</param-name>
            <param-value>6Ldx8eYSAAAAAIyXv7tZAlOm5IGPYkIO1wLKHKMK</param-value>
        </context-param>


        <context-param>
            <description>
                This parameter tells MyFaces if javascript code should be allowed in the
                rendered HTML output.
                If javascript is allowed, command_link anchors will have javascript code
                that submits the corresponding form.
                If javascript is not allowed, the state saving info and nested parameters
                will be added as url parameters.
                Default: "true"
            </description>
            <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ALLOW_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <context-param>
            <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.CHECK_EXTENSIONS_FILTER</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <context-param>
            <description>
                If true, rendered HTML code will be formatted, so that it is "human readable".
                i.e. additional line separators and whitespace will be written, that do not
                influence the HTML code.
                Default: "true"
            </description>
            <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.PRETTY_HTML</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </context-param>

         <context-param>
            <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/taglib/messages.taglib.xml;/WEB-INF/taglib/springsecurity.taglib.xml
            </param-value>
         </context-param>

       <!-- if you want to disable the behaviour completely -->
      <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ERROR_HANDLING</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
      </context-param>
      <!-- if you are using myfaces + facelets don't forget to do this -->
      <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
      </context-param>

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>Redirect Servlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.teamead.fwf.web.RedirectServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>Redirect Servlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/redirect</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <!--
          - Faces Servlet Mapping.
        //-->
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>


        <filter>
           <filter-name>Character Encoding</filter-name>
           <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
           <init-param>
               <param-name>encoding</param-name>
               <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
           </init-param>
           <init-param>
               <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
               <param-value>true</param-value>
           </init-param>
       </filter>

        <!--
          - Spring Security filter chain.
        //-->
        <filter>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        </filter>

        <filter-mapping>
          <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
          <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
          <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
          <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        </filter-mapping>

        <!--
          -  The corresponding filter mapping
        //-->
        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>Character Encoding</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>


        <!--
          - Common data source.
        //-->  
        <resource-ref>
              <description>DB Connection</description>
              <res-ref-name>jdbc/CS_PU</res-ref-name>
              <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
              <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
        </resource-ref>

        <!--
          - Welcome Files.
        //-->
        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>index.jspx</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>



    </web-app>
```

Comment: Can you share your web.xml ?

Comment: See if anything in this thread helps: https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2195568 you might need to pack your war/ear differently.

Comment: Thanks. I resolved the issue in the meantime by switching to Mojarra